# Вывести cookie в zip

Tags: php, cookie

Написал такие строки кода, всё хорошо, но вот запихнуть в зип куки совсем не получается (в куках хранится изображение)-не подскажете как это сделать?
Всё что  меня получилось это закинуть в зип папки где должно быть изображение (но его там нет) и вывести 1 - т.к. изображение в куках 1.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC+4');
$a = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$dir = '/favorite/';
$filename = ".$dir./$a.zip";
if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("Невозможно открыть <$filename>\n");}
$zip->addFromString( $_COOKIE['this.count'],$_COOKIE['fav_cnt'] );
$zip->close();
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename)); 
readfile("$filename");
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Изображение не хранится в куках. Изображение хранится в файловой системе вашего сервера. В куке можно сохранить ПУТЬ к изображению, и конечно же зиповать куки - это бред утопающего*(RFC 2109: макс.размер - 4кб, что мы сэкономим пакованием?.. для локального хранения больших данных умные люди придумали локальное хранилище)*, прочтите хоть один учебник по пхп до конца.
(да и сама по себе попытка паковать.жпг -- это вообще апофеоз тупости)

Comment: и конечно же зиповать куки - это бред утопающего  -это почему?

Comment: @deivan, ну все же очевидно при применении минимальной телепатии: суть архива явно в том, чтобы скачать набор изображений одним файлом. А что касается остального, то легко заметить, что приведенный код является неумело подправленным копипастом из нескольких источников. Соответственно, ТС в целом никогда не открывал учебник PHP, что приводит нас к выбору - отправить человека искать фрилансера либо просто пройти мимо, ибо иначе придется решить задачу за него, что не соответсвует правилам форума.

Comment: ну этот код скопирован из мануала php.net и учебник я открывал, но если не хотите помочь, то зачем столько демагогий? Просто бы прошли мимо и всё
и конечно же зиповать куки - это бред утопающего -это почему?
и на сей вопрос вы так и не ответили

Comment: @нгш
>зачем столько демагогий?

Программирование на удивление мало состоит из непосредственно кода и содержит в себе миллиард стандартов, которые обеспечивают стабильность выполнения, читаемость, расширяемость, переносимость кода. Это все действительно оченьт важные штуки, как только проект расширяется до таких размеров, что один человек не может его запомнить целиком.

> зиповать куки - это бред утопающего

Куки предназначены для хранения текстовых данных малого объема (относящихся к пользователю) и используются при каждом запросе. Зипование как минимум тупо будет забивать проц.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите примеры работы с  `ZipArchive()` вот [тут](http://biohazardhome.blogspot.ru/2011/03/ziparchive-php.html)

Возможно прав нету на ту директорию где собираетесь делать архив?

А что у вас в переменных  `$_COOKIE['this.count']` и `$_COOKIE['fav_cnt']`?

Comment: 101_0013**/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_l_12c1322_13_1600.jpg**http://tarasik.tmweb.ru/index.php/home/2011-11-30-14-29-19/1-main/detail/1-car#
это значение $_COOKIE['fav_image']?